# Java Fast generate string with zero's

Tags: java

I have a code.

```
private static String generateString(int size) {
    StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        s.append("0");
    return s.toString();
}
```

which generate me `0000` for size = 4

How i can simplify this block of code?

Comment: Why do you need to simplify it?

Comment: This is simple enough, isn't it? And you won't get it much faster

Comment: Please prefer readable code. Java is enough faster buddy.

Comment: Exactly what problem are you trying to solve by 'simplifying' this code?

Comment: `String.format("%0" + size + "d", 0);` for `size > 0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "fast" - fast in as few lines of code, or fast for CPU to execute?

Don't use `StringBuffer`. It is thread-safe and heavily synchronized. If anything, `StringBuilder` has much smaller footprint.

Here's an alternative though:

```
char[] c = new char[10];
Arrays.fill(c, '0');
String result = new String(c);
```

It's even lighter than `StringBuilder`, probably as light as it gets. `StringBuilder` internally appends to a `char[]` as well, but not knowing the size upfront it's doing range checking all the time and scaling the buffer as needed. You could construct a `StringBuilder(n)`, but it still would do the wasteful bounds checking and you would have to write the loop for appending yourself.

Comment: Do you have to add a null terminator or is that done automatically?

Comment: @Insertusernamehere No, you don't need that. In Java all arrays are bounded and this String constructor just builds a new String by copying provided array in its entirety.

Comment: Gotcha. C is messing with my Java knowledge =P

Answer (score 4):

Suppose Max value of size is 100 :

```
private static STRING = "0000...";  //  length = 100

private static String generateString(int size) {
    return STRING.substring(0, size);
}
```

Comment: Yeap! that what i need.

Comment: Arrays.copy is working faster than adding to buffer.

Comment: for java7 and above, substring order is O(n) and we suppose that size is limited.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is good but in this case is should use a *`StringBuilder`* instead of a *`StringBuffer`* (Better perfomance and you don't need the synchronized nature of the *`StringBuffer`*)